# Unable to sort date column in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two columns in a table. I can sort the location column asc/desc just fine. However, I cannot do the same thing with the date column. It seems I can sort it once, but whenever I try to sort it again, it does nothing.

Please see the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/2463hsvd/

If you click the 'Date' header, it sorts. However, clicking it again does nothing. This is not the case with the Location column. What am I doing wrong?

controller

```
function myCtrl($scope){
$scope.descending = false;
$scope.columnToOrderBy = 'date';
$scope.data = [
    {
        date: "2014-06-19T05:00:00",
        Location: "California"
    },
    {
       date: "2014-07-13T08:00:00",
       Location: "Texas"
    },
    {
        date: "2013-07-13T08:00:00",
        Location: "Florida"
    }
];  
}
```

html

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="2">
        <tr>
            <th ng-click=" columnToOrderBy ='Date'; descending = !descending">
                Date
            </th>
            <th ng-click=" columnToOrderBy ='Location'; descending = !descending">
                Location
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:columnToOrderBy:descending">
            <td>{{item.date | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma"}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Location}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is `date`, not `Date`

```
<th ng-click=" columnToOrderBy ='Date'; descending = !descending">
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2463hsvd/1/)